# Laravel : How to add a key value into an object?

Tags: laravel

How to add a key value into an object?

I want to add `"tags" => ["foo","bar"]` into every record,demo：

**ArticlesController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = user()->articles;
    dd($articles);  //This is a collection

    //loop the collection,and add `"tags" => ["foo","bar"]` into every record
    $multiplied = $articles->map(function ($item, $key) {
        dd($item);//result below

        //how to write here？

    });
    $newArticles = $multiplied->all();
    dd($newArticles);
    return view('articles', compact('newArticles'));
}
```

result of `dd($item)`：

```
   Article {#498 ▼
         #fillable: array:2 [▶]
         #casts: array:1 [▶]
         #connection: "mysql"
         #table: null
         #primaryKey: "id"
         #keyType: "int"
         +incrementing: true
         #with: []
         #perPage: 15
         +exists: true
         +wasRecentlyCreated: false
         #attributes: array:6 [▼
           "id" => 1
           "title" => "hello"
           "content" => "hello world"
           "user_id" => 2
           "created_at" => "2017-07-23 15:34:52"
           "updated_at" => "2017-07-23 15:34:55"
         ]
         #original: array:6 [▶]
         #dates: []
         #dateFormat: null
         #appends: []
         #events: []
         #observables: []
         #relations: []
         #touches: []
         +timestamps: true
         #hidden: []
         #visible: []
         #guarded: array:1 [▶]
       }
```

**question：**
How to write the code in `map()`?

Comment: what do you want when add into an object? because it can not a record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$item->tags = ['foo', 'bar']; 
return $item;
```

inside map will do the job.

But do the map to $newArticles.

Comment: what does `But do the map to $newArticles.` mean?

Comment: We usually never change the model's collection as some changes can override the predefined methods. So, the usual implementation is first call `all' then do a `map` on to of that to change.

Comment: thanks,I see. here `$newArticles = $multiplied->all();` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

simple

```
$object->new_key="value";
```